# Why is a binary system used instead of decimal system when interpreting voltages?

Tags: voltage, computers, binary

In physical computing, binary is used to perform calculations.  Typically, 1 corresponds to high voltage (3V-5V), and 0 corresponds to low voltage (0V-2V).

Perhaps it is not feasible due to the amount of precision involved, but why is it that people do not use a higher base system such as decimal or hexadecimal when interpreting voltages?

The thought behind this is that if a computational system divides a range of voltages into 10 discrete sub-ranges, then couldn't computational speed be increased?

Instead of using 0V-2V and 3V-5V, perhaps something like the following could be used:

[image: Decimal Voltage Ranges]

I realize that the voltage ranges cannot be be too high; so, if the voltage range of  0V-5V was split up into 10 intervals instead, would there be any issues?

Comment: Why don't you count based on the number of atoms in each finger rather than in whole fingers?

Comment: Can you propose how to implement such elements as registers, adders, multipliers and comparators in your scheme? Now using a simulator you can find out for yourself if they have the same or better speeed, noise immunity, power consumption, and chip area cost compared to the existing binary circuits.

Comment: You've basically just described an Analog to Digital Converter (ADC) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter which maps voltage ranges to integers. A 3-bit 10V ADC would map your voltage range to an integer from 0 to 7. A more common 10-bit ADC maps `0..3.3V` or `0..5V` to `0..1024`.

Comment: Greatly reduced Noise Immunity over worst-case variations in temperature, power supply voltage, even IC chip process variation (strong-N-weak-P vs weak-N-strong-P for example). Without noise immunity, there's no advantage over using an analog adder op-amp circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't usually done because it makes things way more complicated.  For binary, you can get away with one or two transistors to store and read a value.  For 10 values at different voltages you need several transistors and resistors (and possibly other parts as well) to tell one value from another.
Also, it is easier to transfer a simple high or low with out loss.
There are some few places where multilevel storage is used - modern nand flash can store up to three bits of data in one cell using different voltage levels - which are translated to normal binary values for communication with other devices.

Comment: Provided your answer, it seems that interpreting 10 values for voltages would add so much complexity that it wouldn't improve performance.  Is that correct?

Comment: It would add so much complexity that it would probably make performance far worse, as well as making devices much more expensive.  There were (back in the old days) computers built with vacuum tubes that used ring counters to store single decimal digits.  Instead of having a bit, you had a number from zero to 9 in a single storage cell.  This made things ssllooww - slower than even vacuum tubes have to be - and expensive - much more expensive than neccessary.  The 10 tubes needed for the ring counter could have been used as bits and been able to store 0 to 2^10-1 (1023) instead of 0 to 10.

Comment: @JRE: In theory one could use 10 vacuum tubes to store a single decimal digit. The people who actually built such machines were smarter than that. Many early machines used mixed-base bi-quinary coded decimal because it required 2+5=7 tubes, rather than the 10 tubes that would be required to represent a decimal digit directly in a ring counter, or the 8 tubes that would be required to represent a decimal digit as binary-coded decimal (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Radix_economy ). Other early machines used a single Dekatron tube to store and increment/decrement a decimal digit.

Answer (score 0):

With **binary** you get so much utility for much less equipment.  This was very important when the equipment consisted of vacuum tubes and other discrete components.

You can **add** two binary bits with just a few gates.

You can **multiply** binary by 2 by shifting bits left.

You can **move or copy** binary bits with just a voltage and a signal.

All this is much harder to do with multiple valued bits.  That is one of the reasons that the **quantum bit computer** is so hard to produce. Quantum bits can have any value.